# Probability problem regarding rooks on a chessboard

Tags: probability, self-study

Eight rooks are placed in distinct squares of an 8 x 8 chessboard, with all possible replacements being equally likely. Find the probability that all the rooks are safe from one another.

Comment: What is the chance that the rooks occupy all $8$ ranks?  By symmetry that's the chance they occupy all $8$ files, too. If you can show these two events are independent then all you need to do is multiply the chances :-).

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints to get you started.

First how many ways can you place the rooks (without the restriction of being safe)?

The first rook can go on any of the 64 spaces, the next any of the remaining 63, etc.

Now how many places can each rook be placed with the restriction?

The 1st rook can now be placed anywhere again, but how many places can you place the 2nd rook? the 3rd? etc.

Dividing the 2 numbers should give you your probability.

Comment: What I did was: I can place the first rook in (8 x 8) squares, and the next rook in (7 x 7) squares, and so on which makes the number of favourable cases = 8! x 8!. And the total no. of cases is 64 C 8. Can you please check where I am mistaken ?

Comment: The 64 choose 8 calculation divides by $8!$ because order does not matter.  But the $8! \times 8!$ assumes that order does matter.  You can either divide the restricted case by $8!$ to say order does not matter, or take the $8!$ out of the denominator of the choose to say that order does matter.  Either way should give the correct result.